# Sufficient condition for matrix $A$ to be similar to symmetric matrix $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but what are sufficient conditions for a matrix $A$ to be similar to a *symmetric* matrix $B$? For instance, on the Wikipedia page for [symmetric matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix), I see something about when a matrix is "symmetrizable", but I can show that the class of matrices I'm working with is not always symmetrizable.

In particular, I'm interested in the following case: when is $D^{-1} A D^{-1}$ similar to a symmetric matrix? Here, $D$ is a diagonal matrix, and $A$ is of the form $BC^T$, where: $B$ is a $n \times m$ binary matrix, $C$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, and $B_{i,j} = 0 \iff C_{i,j} = 0$.

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer, Uthsav?

Comment: Earth to Uthsav – come in, please.

Comment: Sorry! Had a busy weekend. Yep, your answer sounds good to me. I forgot about the spectral theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to concentrate on the question in the title, and I'm going to assume that we are working over the reals. Symmetric matrices are diagonalizable over the reals, so a necessary condition for $A$ to be similar to a symmetric matrix is for $A$ to be diagonalizable. But that's also a sufficient condition, since if $A$ is diagonalizable, then it is similar to a diagonal matrix, and diagonal matrices are symmetric.